# candle stick chart plotting in android application

Tags: android, graphics, graph, charts, candlestick-chart

I'm working a project  with graph in android. I need to know where i can find the graph libraries to implement candle stick graph related to Forex or any money control institutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

- [Stock-chart](http://code.google.com/p/stock-chart/) is free and open-source. Supports candle-stick charts.
- [Teechart](http://www.steema.com/gallery/charts/4) has specifically designed charts to track financial data. But it's not free.
- [aicharts](http://www.artfulbits.com/products/android/aicharts.aspx) also supports [candle-stick charts](http://www.artfulbits.com/articles/documentation/aicharts/android/com/artfulbits/aiCharts/Types/ChartCandleStickType.html). Not free.
- [achartengine](http://code.google.com/p/achartengine/) is a good open-source charting
  library. However it does not have a candle-stick chart type but [a
  range (high-low) bar chart](http://www.achartengine.org/dimages/temperature_range_chart.png).

Comment: i can plot simple graph with achartengine, but i need to plot candle stick graph and the values passed to it is dynamic,also it's needed to be refreshed in a small interval

Comment: Edit: Added other alternatives.